# Request fails after retrieving JWT token

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, axios

I am using Django JWT with DRF and Vue Js with axios. When a user logs in I retrieve and store the token in local storage which I have verified to work. I then redirect to a new page where I make another request to get data. Every time I redirect to this page I get a 401 not authorized and when I refresh the page it works fine. I checked to make sure the token is stored before making the second request which it is. I attempt to get the data on the redirected page in the created hook. I also create an axios instance to deal with the headers and use a base route and then import that into the files where needed, I am not sure if that has something to do with it. This also only happens when the token has expired and you try to retrieve a new one. Should I be refreshing the token instead of trying to get a new one?

## Axios instance

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  },
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
  withCredentials: true
})
```

## Edit

#### api.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
  },
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
  withCredentials: true
})
```

#### AppLogin.vue

Confirm is triggered by clicking a login button

```
 confirm: function() {
       API.post("accounts/login/", {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
       })
        .then(result => {
          console.log(result.data.token);
          this.token = result.data.token;
          localStorage.setItem("token", this.token);
          this.getUserInfo()
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });

    },
    getUserInfo: function(){
      axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/userinfo/get/", {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'JWT ' + this.token
        }
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data.pos);
          var pos = response.data.pos;
          this.reroute(pos);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    reroute(pos) {
      if (pos == "owner") {
        this.$router.push({ path: "/bizhome" });
      } else {
        this.$router.push({ path: "/" });
      }
    }
```

#### BizHome.vue

This is the page that login redirects to on success

```
created: function() {
    this.getLocations();
  },
  methods: {
    getLocations() {
      API.get("business/")
        .then(response => {
          this.biz = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });

      API.get("locations/")
        .then(response => {
          this.bizLocations = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  }
```

#### solution

Using some advice that I had gotten from YuuwakU below, I added the headers directly to the get calls in the getLocations method to overwrite the axios instance headers. It appeared that the new page loaded before the token was updated in the instance. One drawback to this solution though is that I now have to directly add the headers to all the calls I make. The headers in the instance never to update. I did add  `API.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + result.data.token;` to the confirm method on successful retrieval of the token which should have updated the token for the instance. This did not work for me, if anyone has any ideas I would be interested in hearing them

#### edit 2

I did figure out why the axios instance did not update it is because I was trying to get the token from local stroage in api.js and it was overriding it. Now it works but the token is not persistent so this is not ideal as well. I will update if I find a better solution.

#### Final Update

I finally figured out a good solution. I removed the authorization header from the axios instance in api.js then I removed all the headers from all the axios calls. In the confirm method upon successful login I added this line mentioned previously mentioned `API.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + result.data.token;` and also added the token to local storage. I have a verify token method that runs before pages load. In that method before I make the post request to verify the token I added `API.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + localstorage.getItem('token');` . This allows a user to navigate aways the site and come back and still use the token if valid and does not require the headers to be set on every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why that is happening is because an axios instance has already been created with an expired token that exists in the localStorage. So you have to make sure that the axios instance is updated with a fresh get of the token after login, otherwise you will end up using the old token until a fresh page reload. Try the following:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization() { // Converted to a method, similar concept to a vue data property
      return `JWT  ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
    }
  },
  xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
  withCredentials: true
})
```

OR, you can even use axios interceptors as well to fetch from localStorage with each request:

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    // Do something before request is sent
    config.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
    return config
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but this does not really address my problem. I have no problem checking if users are logged in or not. What is happening is if the token expires and the user login again the page redirects to a home page and the subsequent ajax request fails but refreshing the home page and trying the request again works.

Comment: Hey @Taylor, sorry about the misunderstanding of the problem, I have updated my answer.

Comment: I also think that the problem is with the instance not refreshing but I tried both of your solutions and they did not work unfortunately. What is strange is that I have a verify function that that checks the token on page load. I import it from a utils function that uses the same axios instance. I call the verify funtion in the beforeCreate hook and the get call in the created hook. The verify function works but not the call

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I add code in the edit above

Comment: So many a times when you set a value to a data prop, it loses its reactivity. So, don't depend on `this.token`. Directly `localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);` in the `confirm` method, then in `getUserInfo` use `Authorization: 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('token')`.

Comment: So I added the headers directly into the getLocations get requests and that solved the problem. One thing that puzzles me is that in my confirm method when I retrieved the token I added  `API.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'JWT ' + result.data.token;` which if I understand correctly should update the instances token but that did not work for some reason, any ideas on why that might not work?

Comment: One drawback to this solution though is that I now have to directly add the headers to all the calls I make. The headers in the instance never to update

Comment: Set up axios as vue plugin and in its plugin configuration, use interceptors as I have shown above. Then in your component or store you can directly call `this.$axios` with your call configuration handled at the interceptors. It is even good practise to handle interceptors because you can then use some kind global notification for human readable errors on API calls. Your 4xx 5xx errors. This will surely solve your issue, if it doesn't, then you have misconfigured axios or not used it correctly.

Comment: Also, your `Final update` works, but it isn't idiomatic.